# Use of comma and dash

Tags: punctuation, colons

Which is correct? Please explain this?

1. The system works by making ice at night, when lower power usage means energy is cheaper and lower temperatures require less power to freeze water.
2. The system works by making ice at night- when lower power usage means energy is cheaper and lower temperatures require less power to freeze water.

Comment: Bother are fine.  Some people use a dash to explain, and others use a comma.  BTW, this is a colon :.

Comment: Both are correct, albeit each with somewhat different effect.

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct.
1) The use of comma is for depicting a brief pause, when one has to provide side information about something.
2) The dash is used for explaining something.

Both are used for providing some explanation about a thing that is mentioned in the sentence, an explanation without which the sentence would make sense too, but the writer wants the reader to know more about that thing.
It depends upon the writer what he chooses to use in such a situation.